# Shrinking a div to content size

Tags: html, css

Hello I was wondering is there a way to shrink a div down to its content size(I ask because I have a background color and it just looks ugly when the text height is much shorter than the rest of the div,, which is filled with color? When I put height: auto it's not really shrinking down to the content size; by that I mean the text that I have. Is there a way to provide room past the text cumulative height? Like having the div height be 10 or 15 percent higher than the total height of the content? If you see I put margin:auto on here but it's not really having an effect. Right now this div is in a flexbox but I don't think that's causing the issue. Now in the snippet the height ratio is perfectly fine, but when I do it in a bigger window the height of the div completely overshadows the text because of the color/height of the div. And I'd rather not increase the line-height. Or do I just have to do trial and error and just change the height values until I find something?

-Thanks

```css
.middle {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    order: 2;
    justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.middle div {
  height: auto;
 
}

.box2 {
 
 background-color: #F0ECCA;
 
 
}
```

```html
<div class="middle">
        
         <div class="box">
             <h2> Overview <h2>
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="box2">
              <p>"Yo yo dab dab sample sample sample
                this is a sample sentence this is a sample sentence this is a sample sentence this is a sample sentence this is a sample sentence this is a sample sentence.
              </p>
              

            </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Help me out here, do you want 10-15px space around the content (i.e: you see background colour extend out 10-15px from content)? Or do you want the background colour to stop at the edges of the content (i.e: no padding around)?

Comment: Well the pixels would require me to find the exact height of the content. Not even sure of a way to do that. Pixels or percentage is fine, but I think the other guy got it. Totally forgot I could adjust padding/margin, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `div` that holds the text is doing exactly what you expect it to. The excess background color is actually coming from the `<p>` tag. Setting the margin-top and margin-bottom both to 0 for that element will do what you are looking for.

Why do we need to manually change the margins of the `<p>`? `<p>` tags have default margins provided by the browser.

How do you easily solve issues like this? Open the inspector and choose the "select an element" button (top-left in the chrome console). Hover over the element you are trying to fix and look at the style values and box model provided by the console.